# how to scope C# view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have a view that shows list of people. For said view I created a `PersonListViewModel`

```
class PersonListViewModel { 
    public IEnumerable<Person> People {get;set;}
    public int TotalPersonCount {get;set;}
    public int PeoplePerPage {get;set;}
    public string OrganizationName {get;set;}
}
```

My question is about `Person` class. Where should `Person` class be defined? And what should I call it?

This problem is an instance of more general problem of mapping types between bounded contexts or layers. I understand that I can use AutoMapper and such to do some of this work, but AutoMapper only alleviates the problem but does not solve it.

Here some options that I have considered along with pros and cons:

**Put both `PersonListViewModel` and `Person` classes in the same namespace, e.g. `Whatever.Organization.ViewModels`.**

Pro: `Person` class name shows what it is - a person, and context this class is bound to specified by namespace.
Con: In a presenter where I build this `Person` instance will (most likely) collide with `Person` class from business domain space, so I will have to prefix one of them.
Con: will have to add a namespace to contain view models (not necessarily a problem, since you might, and I do, already have a namespace for view models).

**Nest `Person` inside `PersonListViewModel` class.**
Pro: Can have multiple `Person` classes for different view models.
Pro: `Person` is naturally scoped to a view model it belongs to.
Con: Can not reuse `Person` between views and view models. Inb4: I do believe that ViewModels shall not be reused, I do believe it is to reuse a non-viewmodel object definition in presentation layer when appropriate. This approach does not allow for such reuse, and in 5% of cases where it is necessary - I don't want to create a different pattern.

**Postfix every presentation layer object with *ViewModel**
Pro: solves the problem of reuse and name collisions.
Con: makes no sense since `Person` is only a view model when it contains data for a view, which might or might not be the case -- for example if person instance is given to a [sub]view - then, technically, it will be a view model, but if it is used as a property on `PersonListViewModel` then `Person` is not a view model (no more than `int` of `TotalPersonCount` is a view model, which it is not).

So far I don't have a solution that would make me happy. But solution #1 seems to be most correct (theoretically speaking), still I am hopeful a better solution will be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 3. Why would a `Person` ever be passed to a view if it doesn't contain data for the view? ViewModels in general should only contain the data required by the view. There's nothing wrong with creating a `PersonViewModel` to pass data for a `Person` across that is to be consumed by the view. If the view doesn't require it, don't pass it across.

The fact that you are creating a `PersonListViewModel` implies that you are doing something presentational with a list of people in your view. It makes perfect sense to therefore create a `PersonViewModel` for holding the display data that you will be displaying in your view for each person held within your list.

Comment: *ViewModel means it is an abstraction of a representation of a single view. *ViewModel does not mean it has _a_ _piece_ of data for a view. *ViewModel is a composite build of pieces, each of those pieces is an object, each of those pieces is _not_ a view model. Which is why I distaste option #3 although it is most convenient.

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting point. I like to make the clear distinction between objects that are clearly for presentation vs those that are clearly part of the domain. Adding the ViewModel suffix makes that distinction nicely.

Comment: yes, I agree. By that logic Person from business layer should be called `PersonBusinessObject` (looks weird), and Person in DAL should be `PersonEntity` (is a common practice). I don't mind using suffix per se, maybe if I find a suffix to indicate the layer `Person` belongs to, not a (incorrect) role `Person` plays.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with the third option. As you say it's allowing this to be used between different view models and I don't see any OOP issues with just passing a single Person element to a partials for when you are looping over Person list.